# How do I move a group of controllers into a folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated a group of scaffolds with edited code inside, but now I want to move these groups of controllers into a folder, let's say its name is `admin`. How do I do it?

I put `Admin::` in the controller already, moved them into a folder already, but still there is an error.

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: Whats the error thats popping up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The piece I don't see above is what you're telling Rails' routing engine.  This is probably what you're missing.  If you're using Rails 3, I wrote an article about this:

[Routing in Ruby on Rails 3](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/02/routing-in-ruby-on-rails-3/)

The section "Namespaced Routes" details how to setup the mapping in your routes file.  Here's a code sample:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

You already have the other parts done.  If you're using Rails 2.x, try this instead:

```
map.namespace(:admin) do |admin| 
  admin.resources :posts
end
```

I'll admit, I haven't tried this last snippet but it looks solid.  I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 -- Question, this is for an organization benefit only right (more structured files)? It's possible to still do the namespace w/out the nested folders?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I believe Rails will require the folder structure to mimic the nested namespacing.  Rails expects all classes to have file structures that match the class names, which is a nice convention. As for the benefit being organizational - you're right, there's no added functionality that you couldn't do with a flat file structure and no namespacing. But the added organization can really aid development of larger applications.